# I do not get the last digit of a number when using mod 10 rather just getting an output of 0?

Tags: java

when I do 57%10 it does not give me an answer of 7 rather it gives an output of 0,  even when I do 57/10 it gives me 0. Please help solve this issue.

[this is the code written](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wjf3p.png)

```
class main{

   public static void main(String[] args)   
   {
     int d=57;
     int c=d%10;
     System.out.println(c);
   }
}
```

[and the output is coming as 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ym3wj.png)

(I am writting my program on a website called repl.it)

Comment: Do not post pictures of code, copy and paste the text here.

Comment: Please don't include images of code - we can't copy/paste that and run it. Also, the number of exclamation points you include in your question does not influence the amount of effort people will put forward.

Comment: @sleepToken Oh I am sure it does influence the amount of effort people will put forward, just not the way he wants!

Comment: Considering that your image shows `57 % 10` and your question mentions `56 % 10` I don't put much faith in your question.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to save your file:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is definetely producing 7 as output, I just tried it out.
Are you sure, you are running the class that you showed us?
For example, your second picture shows that you run Main.java. But in your first pichture the class is called main (with lowercase m). But the file name and the class name should be identical.

Comment: https://repl.it/@saurabh270/java-test-world there check this website my code is there. (EDITED)Oh wait I just figured out the problem your lowercase suggestion was correct but usually when I write my code in that website I don't change it and it gives me an absolutely correct answer

Answer (score 5):

You may need to recompile and run the newly compiled code. The code which you have shown works as intended.  *Also make sure that you save the changes to the source file before compiling, just to make sure you're compiling the latest changes*

Comment: @WJS, yet this is probably the right answer

Comment: Definitely an answer. OP says they do not get the expected result. I'm providing the answer why they aren't getting the expected result. Keep in mind, the question is **NOT** *HOW* to get the last digit, but *WHY* getting the last digit isn't working.

Comment: I think that downvote isn't correct

Comment: While I don't think this question in its current state *deserves* an answer, I don't think @loganrussell48 should be punished for it.

Comment: it's good of you to explain the downvote but I think the question should be closed more than a bad answer

Comment: This whole post is a disaster. The *question* is really just a statement with a `?` at the end. Thanks for explaining though. I'd rather know why I got downvoted than not know

Comment: @WJS instead you did well to explain, but sometimes we can be even harder, suggest a change or modify ourselves  or close it... if there is no change, then downvote ... 
especially with novices

Answer (score 0):

I am able to reproduce your problem in repl.it.
Just change you class name to `Main` (uppercase Main).

```
class Main {...}
```

It simply doesn't show you error message:

> Error: Could not find or load main class Main

and runs previous version of complied class.
I also suggest to use better IDE - Eclipse or IntelliJ